# When is macOS Big Sur EOL, meaning there will be no more security fixes?

Tags: security, big-sur

I have a relatively new MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014), which works wonderfully and is in daily use.

I was shocked to discover that macOS Monterey is not supported on my relatively new machine ([macOS Monterey is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551)). Are there any technical reasons for this? Or is the only reason to force the sale of new devices?

When is macOS Big Sur EOL, meaning there will be no more security fixes? I did not find a lifecycle document with specific dates at Apple KB.

Comment: Love the fact you’re in IT yourself but calling a 2014 model „relatively new“. I totally agree it’s shocking, it’s just funny because most people would even call a 3-yo device old (considering how fast the modern industry develops and they’re releasing a new model each year)

Comment: Once upon a time, you had to pay for a major OS upgrade. When they became free (I think OS X 8 was the first free upgrade), the price of the machine did not go up. So your "new" MacBook Air, which shipped with 10.9, has gotten free upgrade to 10.10, 10.11, 10.12, 10.13, 10.14, 10.15, and 11. That's at least several hundred dollars in OS costs that you could count against the price of a new machine.

Comment: That kind of analysis assumes that people buy each upgrade and wouldn't skip versions if they were paid (yes they would), and also ignores the environmental impact of tossing perfectly could machines do to arbitrary software restrictions. It's especially ironic given the self-proclaimed eco-friendliness of these devices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There do not appear to be technical reasons for not allowing you to install macOS Monterey on your MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014), as you can install macOS Monterey on your device in an unofficial way. Performance may not be great, but (in my opinion) that should not block you from installing it (though a warning message would be understandable). [There were some devices that Apple dropped that did have issues with the new update, but the OpenCore Legacy Patcher developers were able to fix them](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MONTEREY-DROP.html#previously-broken-hardware), but your device was never one of the models affected from what I can tell.

Nobody knows for sure when macOS Big Sur will stop getting security updates, but as Skye-AT and Tetsujin mentioned, Apple usually provides security updates for OSes up to 3 versions prior, so you probably still have at least 3 years of support.

When that ends, if you wish to install macOS Monterey, [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/START.html) supports [your MacBook Air](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html) and [macOS Monterey](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MONTEREY-DROP.html), so you can follow [their instructions](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/INSTALLER.html#downloading). Warning: I have not attempted these steps (fortunately my Mac is from 2015), so do so at your own risk (and feel free to use any up-to-date guide at that time.) The final version of macOS Monterey released just a couple days ago, so there still may be some undiscovered bugs running it on unofficial hardware, but it [appears so far](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MONTEREY-DROP.html) there are no bugs on your model.

Comment: I have a MacBook Air mid-2012 running the latest Monterey with OpenCore Legacy Patcher for a few months now and it works great, even OTA updates work. I just got a "relatively new" MacBook Pro mid-2014 and also managed to get it updated to Monterey. Big fan of OpenCore Legacy Patcher!

Answer (score 25):

Apple does not provide that kind of information. However, the materials needed to make a guess can be found on [this site](https://endoflife.date/macos) ([source, it's MIT licensed](https://github.com/endoflife-date/endoflife.date)). From the information as far as I can tell on this site, it seems that support will be provided for basically three years from the release of it's version.

This is just my opinion, but I wouldn't call a 7-year-old PC a "relatively new". It's old.

Comment: "It's old". 7 years made a lot of difference in technology a few decades ago. But it's not like there have been huge breakthroughs for computers since 2014. If OP isn't editing huge video files or working on 3D games, a 2014 laptop is probably still perfectly fine. Planned obsolescence is a widespread, despicable trend. It's perfectly fine to not accept it.

Comment: @EricDuminil Well, that's why I said "my opinion" - In my book, any computer that can be rounded to 10 is old. And I think there was some huge breakthrough (14nm to 10nm, 7nm, Intel CPUs to Apple M1, DDR3 to DDR4, SATA to NVMe, etc...) But yeah, if OP is just browsing or listening or watching then it's not that much old.

Answer (score 7):

The "rule of thumb" is 10 years - 5 years full support followed by 5 years partial support.

Apple publishes a list which covers hardware repair. Software support *generally* but not *absolutely* follows this list.
[Getting a service for your Apple product after its warranty has expired](https://support.apple.com/HT201624)

In general, if it's on the Vintage list it will still get security updates even after it no longer gets full OS upgrades. Once on the Obsolete list, support is EoL.

Historically, Apple have issued regular security updates for OSes up to "three prior". Currently, Mojave still gets security updates, earlier OSes don't. [That is likely to change as of now, as Mojave becomes "four prior".]